# Updating entity data to Azure storage table with Azure Storage Explorer Query

Tags: azure, azure-storage

can you help me please? I want to update all entities with a query.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to write a query like `UPDATE Table Where SomeProperty = SomeValue`?

Comment: Yes exactly :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `UPDATE Table Where SomeProperty = SomeValue` kind of update operation which are available in a relational database, unfortunately it is not possible to do so with Azure Tables. Simply put, you can't issue an update query against a table in Azure Tables to update entities in that table.

What you need to do is first fetch the entities and once the entities are fetched, you update those entities on the client side (i.e. in the application where you fetched the entities) and then perform update operation on these entities.

You could possibly do an [`Entity Group Transaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions) for the entities that you need to update to avoid multiple network calls (each entity update operation is a separate network call) and get transaction support. However there're some requirements for performing an `Entity Group Transaction` which can be found on the page I linked.